# Changing primary key int type to serial

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, auto-increment

Is there a way to change existing primary key type from int to serial without dropping the table? I already have a lot of data in the table and I don't want to delete it.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Converting an int to a serial [more or less only means adding a sequence default to the value](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL), so to make it a serial;

- Pick a starting value for the serial, greater than any existing value in the table
  `SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM mytable`
- Create a sequence for the serial (tablename_columnname_seq is a good name)
  `CREATE SEQUENCE test_id_seq MINVALUE 3` (assuming you want to start at 3)
- Alter the default of the column to use the sequence
  `ALTER TABLE test ALTER id SET DEFAULT nextval('test_id_seq')`
- Alter the sequence to be owned by the table/column;
  `ALTER SEQUENCE test_id_seq OWNED BY test.id`

[A very simple SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7427c/1).

And as always, make a habit of running a full backup *before* running altering SQL queries from random people on the Internet ;-)

Comment: But how can we used this incremented value in different table as foreign key .It is giving null value in other to which it is linked.

Comment: Can anyone explain why the permission ownership `ALTER SEQUENCE test_id_seq OWNED BY test.id` query is important? I have mismatched schemas so cant run this.

Comment: @ConnorWilloughby From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) (for PostgreSQL version 12) describing the practical effects of using SERIAL type for a table column, 'the sequence is marked as “owned by” the column, so that it will be dropped if the column or table is dropped.' That is, a DROP of the column or table will now cascade, getting rid of the sequence as well. Convenience!

Answer (score -3):

```
-- temp schema for testing
-- ----------------------------
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE bagger
        ( id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , tralala varchar
        );

INSERT INTO bagger(id,tralala)
SELECT gs, 'zzz_' || gs::text
FROM generate_series(1,100) gs
        ;

DELETE FROM bagger WHERE random() <0.9;
-- SELECT * FROM bagger;

        -- CREATE A sequence and tie it to bagger.id
        -- -------------------------------------------
CREATE SEQUENCE bagger_id_seq;
ALTER TABLE bagger
        ALTER COLUMN id SET NOT NULL
        , ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('player_id_seq')
        ;
ALTER SEQUENCE bagger_id_seq
        OWNED BY bagger.id
        ;
SELECT setval('bagger_id_seq', MAX(ba.id))
FROM bagger ba
        ;

     -- Check the result
     -- ------------------
SELECT * FROM bagger;

\d bagger
\d bagger_id_seq
```

Comment: What does this do? can you explain why it works or maybe other possible solutions?

Comment: Well:it createsa table(which the OP did not do),populates it with random values(which  the OP did not do), adds a seria l*oldstyle*  (which  the OP intended) and makes it a primary key (which the  OP intended)