# Postgresql - primary key - reset counter - no sequence associated

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, reset

I don't know how to reset postgresql primary key to 1.

select pg_get_serial_sequence('table_name', 'primary_key_column') returns empty string so there is no sequence associated with this pk.

Comment: What is the type of the primary key column. Connect to your database via psql, then `\d table_name` to see which sequence is used for the column in the `Modifiers` part.

Comment: In Modifiers I got "not null" and nothing more.

Comment: Ｔhen the column don't have a sequence associated. When create table, you could use `bigserial` for the id column, instead of `bigint`.

Comment: Ok, but am I able to reset the counter?

Comment: If you want to to cast the int to serial, refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578427/changing-primary-key-int-type-to-serial or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307835/how-to-convert-primary-key-from-integer-to-serial , and learn to search first, it's very easy to find the answers.