# Django / postgresql - model with only foreign keys

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a model which looks like this:

```
class InputTypeMap(models.Model):
    input_type = models.ForeignKey(InputType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    training = models.ForeignKey(Training, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.ForeignKey(Gender, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When I try to create instances of this model with:

```
InputTypeMap.objects.create(input_type=input_type,
                            training=training,
                            gender=gender,
                            category=category)
```

I get an exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, Maintenance, Female, MareGielding, No).
```

From the error message it seems to me that a ID key for the new entry is not generated.

This code has worked as I expected for quite some time, but has "suddenly" started to fail locally - probably after a `apt get upgrade`. When I run the same code with sqlite or Postgres-10.14 things continue to work as before. It is not clear to me whether this is a bug in my code (most probable ...), Django or Postgres. I am using Django version 3.1.2

I have version 9.6 of the Postgres server

Comment: This `id` field is presumably (part of) a primary key, and these can not be NULL. Never were.

Comment: Yes - the ID key is the primary key; and since I have not added it to the model it should be created and populated automatically - I thought?

Comment: It is only generated if the caller omits it, or supplies `DEFAULT` as a *value*  for it.

Comment: @user422005 when you change data base have you apply migration again or only change the database.

Comment: Can you provide a git repo?  This will be difficult to debug without a MRE.

Comment: If you somehow had your ID field altered on the database level and you want to make it an autoincrementing sequence again do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578427/changing-primary-key-int-type-to-serial

Comment: Can you post the Postgres table definition? Seems like you may have lost the autogeneration of the PK id field when you upgraded. What were you on before 9.6? And why do you say 10.14 works if 9.6 is the upgraded version?

Comment: Have you run `./manage.py migrate` since you upgraded the system?

Answer (score 1):

most probably, that is a primary_key problem, in my case i added to my model something like:

```
person_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

adapt my views to it, and it solved it,

Answer (score 0):

[Changing primary key int type to serial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578427/changing-primary-key-int-type-to-serial) solved it for me.

credit goes to [nishit chittora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5081918/nishit-chittora).