# Change datatype of column in Postgresql

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I have a DB migration file -

```sql
create table enqueries(
    id integer primary key ,
    message text not null
    );
```

I want to change data type of "ID" to **bigserial** by creating another migration file
`alter table emi_tncs alter column id type bigserial;`,as generation type for "ID" is **IDENTITY** in Java Springboot.

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

But this shows error.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578427/changing-primary-key-int-type-to-serial

Comment: With modern Postgres versions `identity` columns are recommended over `serial` (or `bigserial`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's what I want to know,how to change integer to serial.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578427/changing-primary-key-int-type-to-serial - but again using an `generated always as identity` is highly recommended over the non-standard serial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added another migration file with the following query

```
ALTER TABLE enqueries ALTER COLUMN id
ADD GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY;
```

It solved the problem.