# Sequelize "null value in column of relation violates not-null constraint" on auto increment field after migrate from MySQL to Postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to migrate from MySQL to Postgres, I used pgLoader to move my data, reading operations seems to work fine but I am having this issue - When I am trying to create a new record using model.create() I am getting `SequelizeDatabaseError: null value in column of relation violates not-null constraint`

My sequelize looks like that:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DB_NAME,
    process.env.DB_USER,
    process.env.DB_PASS,
    {
        dialect: 'postgres',
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT,
        schema: process.env.DB_PORT.DB_SCHEMA,
        logging: false,
        dialectOptions: {
            ...(process.env.DB_PORT === "5432" ? {} : addSSL())
        }
    }
);

const exampleModel = sequelize.define(
    "exampleModel",
    {
        ExampleID: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        Name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
        },
    },
);
```

But when I do:

```
await model.create({
  Name: "FooBaz",
});
```

I am getting that error.
It was working fine with MySQL but now I am facing this issue.

I am not sure what should I do in this case, because it explicitly say that it's null reseting the counter won't have effect.

Edit:
Running `sequelize.sync({alter: true})`
prints the following

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "schema"."exampleModel" ("ExampleID"  SERIAL , "Name" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("ExampleID"));
```

Followed by some alter tables lines.
But when I checked ExampleID type it's still integer (as it was on MySQL), the alter doesn't change it.
So do I need to convert it serial manually?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the complete `create table` (SQL) statement for the table in question. Is it possible you used a `check` constraint in MySQL for the not null?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I edited and included the create table commend and additional comment

Comment: `serial` **is** [an integer](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL). It's just a shorthand notation for a not null integer getting its default value from a sequence. And if your INSERT passes an explicit NULL value for that column, then that will result in a constraint violation. The INSERT should not provide any value for that column (which is different than providing a NULL value). Note that `identity` columns are preferred over `serial` these days.

Comment: So how can I resolve it? sequelize provides INSERT(DEFAULT, values...), so it uses the default option for the column, which would be the sequence in this case

Comment: You need to convince your obfuscation layer to generate an INSERT statement that does not mention the column `"ExampleID"`, so `insert into "exampleModel" ("Name", "createdAt", "updatedAt") values (...)`. Btw: the use of quoted identifiers is [strongly discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names)

Comment: I edited my previous comment, sequelize sends insert into... (DEFAULT, name, more_values...) so DEFAULT is being passed to postgres at the place of the ID

Comment: If that is really the SQL statement generated, then the error won't occur

Comment: The column ExampleID right now has no default value

Comment: Then you didn't define it as a `serial` as you claimed you did

Comment: I didn't say I defined it as serial, I said sequelize tried to do it but apperantly it didn't work. And I am having trouble to manually do it because I am getting ERROR:  cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression
SQL state: 0A000 to set default to use interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The problem is that pgLoader doesn't copy autoincrement correctly, to fix it you need to set it manually on postgres using sequence, check here for instructions.
[Changing primary key int type to serial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578427/changing-primary-key-int-type-to-serial)

After fixing it, the problem resolved.

Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name