# cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression - trying to set up default value for custom column name

Tags: postgresql

I am having this table which I migrated from MySQL using pgLoader

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schema.example
(
    "ExampleID" integer NOT NULL,
    "Name" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "idx_43997_PRIMARY" PRIMARY KEY ("ExampleID"),
)
```

I am trying to convert the ExampleID to be serial so it will auto increment using this method:
[Changing primary key int type to serial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578427/changing-primary-key-int-type-to-serial)

So I am doing

```
CREATE SEQUENCE example_id_seq MINVALUE 3
```

Which works fine, but then

```
ALTER TABLE example ALTER "ExampleID" SET DEFAULT nextval('example_id_seq')
```

Gives the error:

```
ERROR:  cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression
SQL state: 0A000
```

But if I remove the "" and just put ExampleID like that:

```
ALTER TABLE example ALTER ExampleID SET DEFAULT nextval('example_id_seq')
```

I will get the error

```
ERROR:  column "exampleid" of relation "example" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
```

Comment: Please show us the complete INSERT statement you are using. And get rid of the dreaded quoted identifiers which are the reason for `column "exampleid" does not exist`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I edited the question to include that

Comment: I don't see an `INSERT` in your question. But your setup works if used correctly: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5c04464db9d4fccdb12d570beb720de9 - although the use of `identity` columns is highly recommended with modern Postgres versions: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b3181f9d6dfda030fed66c83aa18cb9e

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you so much for your help, it turns out I forgot to put ' ' so I tried to do nextval(example_id_seq) and that's why I got the error

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem was that unlike in the example

```
ALTER TABLE example ALTER "ExampleID" SET DEFAULT nextval('example_id_seq')
```

I forgot to put ' ' next to the sequence name so it was

```
ALTER TABLE example ALTER "ExampleID" SET DEFAULT nextval(example_id_seq)
```

The column reference was that it mistaken the sequence for column name reference.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this mistake. You helped me find my analogical error with forgotten apostrophes :)

Comment: but what is the answer ?

Comment: 1. ALTER TABLE "ActivityLogType" ALTER "Id" SET DEFAULT nextval("ActivityLogType_Id_seq")
==> error : cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression
SQL state: 0A000
2. ALTER TABLE ActivityLogType ALTER Id SET DEFAULT nextval(ActivityLogType_Id_seq)
 ==> ERROR:  relation "activitylogtype" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01

Answer (score 8):

To add the default string value in the column created through pgadmin dashboard need to wrap the string around ***single quotes***.

Answer (score 0):

For me, only the below is working

```
 ALTER TABLE "ActivityLogType" ALTER COLUMN "Id" SET DEFAULT nextval('"ActivityLogType_Id_seq"');
```