# Insert into without null values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I don't understand why even if I set the non-null select to do the insert I still get the error that I am trying to enter null values. As a context I am trying to insert two columns from another table into a new table.

```
CREATE TABLE t.tb_c    
(
    id  INT NOT NULL,
    itm CHARACTER(5) NOT NULL,
    des CHARACTER(120) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_item PRIMARY KEY (item_id)
);

INSERT INTO t.tb_c (itm)
    SELECT itm 
    FROM erp.tb_d
    WHERE itm IS NOT NULL;



 INSERT INTO t.tb_c (des)
        SELECT des
        FROM erp.tb_d
        WHERE des IS NOT NULL;
```

I get this error:

> SQLState: 23502
> Short Description: AN UPDATE INSERT OR SET VALUE IS NULL BUT THE OBJECT COLUMN CANNOT CONTAIN NULL VALUES
>
> ERROR: the null value for the «des» violates the restriction not null
> DETAIL:  The row is  (90002, AA111, null).
> SQL state: 23502

Comment: Technically you never insert single column - you are always inserting entire row. For unspecified columns (like `des`) SQL tries to write null values (unless default value is specified) - but you can easily see that this cannot succeed.

Comment: Please add the create table command of the second table

Comment: @Arvo I want to insert the values from both columns, chech the edit i made

Comment: You need to fill multiple columns at once, not after each other, meaning insert into...select col1, col2 from...where... But it's difficult to provide an exact command without knowing about your second table structure and data.

Comment: CONSTRAINT pk_item PRIMARY KEY (item_id) is wrong. there is no column item_id.

Comment: Re "I want to insert the values from both columns, chech the edit i made" - this way you will insert two rows. Like I said, you cannot insert single columns - database is not excel table. In SQL you will always insert entire row with all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this insert:

```
INSERT INTO t.tb_c (itm, des)
SELECT itm, des
        FROM erp.tb_d
        WHERE des IS NOT NULL AND itm IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I want to inset all the values from des and itm that are not null. How could i make it

Comment: Check my edit with the insert you need.

Comment: what's about the id column?

Comment: My id column is filled with a sequence, this is the solution that works to me, TY

Comment: Thank you for giving feedback, in future it would be nice when you provide such information directly when asking your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table t.tb_c  alter column itm  drop not null;
alter table t.tb_c  alter column des  drop not null;
```

change id from int to serial follow=>
[Changing primary key int type to serial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578427/changing-primary-key-int-type-to-serial)

---

or

```
ALTER TABLE t.tb_c ALTER COLUMN itm SET DEFAULT '';
ALTER TABLE t.tb_c ALTER COLUMN des  SET DEFAULT '';
```

change id from int to serial follow=>
[Changing primary key int type to serial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578427/changing-primary-key-int-type-to-serial)